# Escaping characters not working properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Android app version 1.0.53

Example question: [Does using the same drive letter for DFS replication on Windows Server 2012 R2 cause any known issues?](https://serverfault.com/q/661060/23513)

Answers using quotation marks or back slashes ( \ ) are not showing correctly. Going to the web page on Chrome works, and clicking Edit in the app will let me see what the author intended.

OnePlus One phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working as of version 1.0.56